# How does Membership.ValidateUser method access a database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, login-control

I wanted to build a membership system at the beginning of my MVC project and I used Membership.ValidateUser method to verify credentials. However I could not understand how does this method access my database and check my email and password informations.

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Login")]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel loginModel)
{
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(loginModel.Email, loginModel.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loginModel.Email, true);
            return Json(true);
        }

        return new JsonNetResult() 
        { Data = new { Error = true, Messages = new[] { new { Message = "Wrong username or password" } } } };
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It' used the `MembershipProvider` specified on your Web.config file to validate the user. By default, it uses [DefaultMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: <add name="MyMembershipProvider" type="MyProject.Domain.Administration.Domain.Membership.MyMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="MembershipDb" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="99" minRequiredPasswordLength="1" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" /> how does it get which database or table i use to hold my credentials

Comment: Your data store is defined in your connection string which is referenced in the code in your comment by connectionStringName="MembershipDb" so it uses the DB in your connection string you've defined in your web.config named MembershipDb

Answer (score 2):

Membership.ValidateUser method at first check membership defaultProvider in your web.config file which matches with name that you provide like below:

```
<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
         connectionStringName="Context" applicationName="myapp" 
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" 
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" 
         passwordFormat="Hashed" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" 
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Above configuration will call .net framework abstraction class MembershipProvider -> ValidateUser (abstract method) which implementation lies in  SqlMembershipProvider -> ValidateUser method that you have configured in your web.config file [like above].In that method it simply call two store procedures of your database , first one is  aspnet_Membership_GetPasswordWithFormat which check your application name, username , last login activity date and current time and based on that makes you authenticate and secondly call to other store procedure which name is aspnet_Membership_UpdateUserInfo which is self explanatory as you realize which update aspnet_membership table with columns like islockedout, lastlockoutdate, failedpasswordattemptcount.. etc.

Hope this helps you.